# I cannot select main class on netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I created the easiest project "Hello world". But I cannot run it because I cannot choose the main class.

```
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A**

1. Right click on your project
2. Select *Properties*
3. Click *Run*
4. Select your class *Package.ClassName*
5. Click *OK* button

**Solution B**

1. Right click on your project
2. Select *Set Configuration*, choose *Customize*
3. Select your class *Package.ClassName*